# Copiar una APP de Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Estoy tratando de migrar unas aplicaciones en java de un servidor que tiene Apache Tomcat 6, a un servidor mas nuevo, con Apache Tomcat 9 (o podría ser el mismo Apache Tomcat 6), me gustaría saber si eso es posible sin tener el código fuente de dichas aplicaciones.
Este proceso lo estoy haciendo ya que necesito montar las aplicaciones en un servidor mas actualizado, ya que el servidor fuente (donde están alojadas las aplicaciones) se encuentra en Windows Server 2003, y el nuevo cuenta con Windows Server 2019, no se si eso afecte en algo.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Hay un archivo .war de la aplicación?

Comment: Si, tiene su respectivo .war

Comment: Normalmente basta con copiar el .war; a menos que la aplicación requiera  recursos externos no contenidos en él.

Comment: Con la carpeta y el .war deberia ser suficiente entonces? Solo copiandolo y ya? @Sal

Comment: Sólo el war, la carpeta se crea automáticamente.

Comment: Puede haber muchas otras consideraciones, pero serían sólo especulaciones nuestras ante el desconocimiento de la arquitectura, ej. ¿la aplicación usa base de datos?.

Comment: No, solo es una aplicacion. solo con el .war y la carpeta del proyecto funciono, si quieres redacta la respuesta y te la marco como correcta, gracias por tu ayuda c: @Sal